# PHP file_put_contents simultaneous requests

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I have a single php script that can be called by thousands of clients,
The job of the script is to append data sent by clients to a single file
I use `file_put_contents($file_pointer, $data,FILE_APPEND)`;

Is there a possibility of data getting overwritten by other request while one is reading from it
or
is there any possibilities of read write conflicts

I tried searching internet but its too complex and vague to get a clear answer from any of the searches!!

Comment: Yes, if you have thousands of requests at a time, it is very possible. You may want to look at other options for storing that data, such as a database.

Comment: This is definitely a use case for a database. Time to stop using file-based data storage.

Comment: thanks for the comments !!, I am assuming that each call to the script will be managed by server and serviced only one at a time..am i thinking wrong ?

Comment: Yes that's right, although HTTP requests can be served in parallel. If they're all trying to access a single physical file, there will be contention. Normally only one process can have write access to a file at once, otherwise you get a big risk of conflicts and corruption. So the result of such an architecture will either be massive file corruption, and/or data being overwritten by processes which had a stale read copy, and/or huge performance problems as processes queue up to access the file one at a time. Again, just use a database - they are perfectly designed for this kind of situation.

Comment: Correct. Webservers are meant to serve many requests all at once, and each request doesn't care about the other requests

Comment: Yes database sounds like a great option , but i want to keep it as cheap as possible , how about i try using a locking mechanism like flock or  file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); does this seem like a viable option ?

Comment: What makes you think a database is expensive? MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, SQLite are all free/open-source databases, just off the top of my head. And if you're thinking of buying hosting to run your PHP application online, almost all the packages you can buy will come with at least one of those database engines included.

Comment: `does this seem like a viable option`...if you don't mind have 999 processes sitting and waiting (and thus consuming your server resources, and leaving users hanging) while the 1st one uses the file, then yes it is. Consider how long it might take until process 1000 gets to the front of the queue. That is ineffecient and creates a poor user experience. Also if there's a lot of data in the file, then loading it all into memory and searching through it to find the bit you want to update is also very inefficient compared to a SQL query. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: If you're simply writing new stuff to the file without reading anything, e.g. like a log file, then you _might_ get away with it, but doing some load testing would be appropriate.

Comment: P.S. While the question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bac703c6-a761-4d75-bd30-7d9ab7a9a859/file-handling-problem-in-aspnet-during-concurrent-request?forum=csharpgeneral) is initially about asp.net, the answer provided is actually quite general and provides some sensible advice about how you might architect a solution for high-volume concurrent requests to write to a file, which would be applicable in almost any programming language. Its ultimate advice is "use an existing logging module"...which again would be applicable to anything, including PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed responses @ADyson, before I start doing database based solution wanted to make sure that the motivation behind it was correct and I understand the problem correctly :)

Comment: You can use `FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX` as flags together (using the pipe to logical or it). this will lock the file and allows only ONE process writing into it. Once completed the lock is removed and another process can do. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php